# No ui app running in foreground?

Tags: blackberry, background-foreground

Can I create app with out ui and running in foreground?

To avoid app to be killed when running in background and low resource.

Sorry for my english.
Thank you for any comment.

Comment: What is the definition of 'foreground' if it has no UI? You can certainly create an application with no UI, but the rest of your question is confusing. It would be helpful if you clicked the edit link beneath it and added additional details to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this BB tutorial - [Create a Background Application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-Background-Application/ta-p/445226).